# How to make below code fast, efficient and great time complexity

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, time-complexity

The code below is working properly. However, how can I improve its speed, efficiency and time complexity

Assume I have 1000 country, state and city data entries in MongoDB collection. I want to retrieve all the city data by matching country id and state id from MongoDB collection.

```
// @route   GET citylist/:countryid/:stateid

// @desc    get all the city from mongodb for countryid and stateid
```

```
router.get("/citylist/:countryid/:stateid", (req, res) => {
  const isValidCountryid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid( req.params.countryid);
  const isValidStateid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.stateid);

  if (isValidCountryid && isValidStateid) {
    CityModel.find({
      country_id: req.params.countryid,
      state_id: req.params.stateid
    })

      .then(cities => {
        if (!cities || !cities[0]) {
          return res.status(404).json({ msg: "City not found" });
        } else {
          res.json(cities);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));

  } else {
    res.json({ msg: "Country or State Id is not valid" });
  }
});
```

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/ then here.

Comment: firstly make sure that country_id and state_id fields are indexed.